# Opencv: Como importar lib automatico

Tags: c++, opencv

Bom dia, eu estou começando a programar com OpenCV em C++ com MinGW, mas estou tendo dificuldade com os arquivos lib. Toda vez que preciso compilar um programa, eu preciso colocar, por exemplo, `-llibopencv_videoio330`. Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de tornar isso automático. Já criei uma variável `LIBRARY_PATH`, mas não parece ter funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias formas. Você pode criar um arquivo de script (Batch no Windows, Bash no Linux, por exemplo) para automatizar essa compilação. Também pode usar um [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). Mas eu te sugiro usar um gerenciador de configuração como o [CMake](https://cmake.org/) para gerar os arquivos de projeto que você vai utilizar na plataforma e compilador adequados.

Ao criar o arquivo do CMake há um comando chamado [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) que "magicamente" encontra as dependências de uma biblioteca que também expor uma "interface CMake" (como é o caso do OpenCV). E há também um comando chamado [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) que faz exatamente o que você quer: linka as bibliotecas corretas. Logo, você pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim no seu script de CMake:

```
. . .
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui imgproc)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
. . .
target_link_libraries(MeuProjeto ${OpenCV_LIBS})
. . .
```

E aí, quando você gerar o projeto (isto é, o projeto do Visual Studio, se usar esse compilador, ou o Makefile se usar algum outro), o CMake vai sozinho encontrar onde estão as bibliotecas do OpenCV e referenciar no seu projeto. E quando você compilar depois, com esse projeto gerado, tudo vai funcionar transparentemente.

O CMake tem uma curvinha de aprendizagem chata (especialmente porque a documentação não é lá essas coisas, na minha opinião), mas vale a pena. Se for te ajudar, [este meu projeto no Github](https://github.com/luigivieira/CamTest) usa OpenCV em C++ e emprega o CMake pra fazer exatamente o que eu te sugeri acima. Dá uma olhada no arquivo `CMakeLists.txt` na raíz do projeto.